# Variable based on browser / device width

Tags: jquery, variables, resize, caroufredsel

I'm using caroufredsel to create a product slider. I have this code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('body').attr('id') === 'index') {
    $('#mycarousel').carouFredSel({
        circular: false,
        infinite: false,
        auto: false,
        width: "200%",
        align: "left",
        prev : ".mycarousel-prev",
        next : ".mycarousel-next",
        responsive:true,
        easing: "easeOutBounce",
        items: {width: "auto",visible: {min:1, max:4}},
        swipe: true,
        scroll : {
          items : 2
        }
    });

  $("#mycarousel").touchwipe({
        preventDefaultEvents: false,
        wipeLeft: function() {
          $('#mycarousel').trigger('next', 2);
          return false;
        },
        wipeRight: function() {
          $('#mycarousel').trigger('prev', 2);
          return false;
        }
      });


};
});
```

Now I need to change number of items to scroll ("items : 2" in caroufredsel function and 'next', 2 or 'prev', 2 in touchwipe) from number 2 to specific number depending on my layout for each media query.

So I have to get the width of my layout:

```
var windowsize = $('#header .nav > .container').width();
```

and then make some if statements, e.g

```
if (windowsize < 720) {
      var passItems = 1;
    } else if (windowsize > 720) {
    var passItems = 3;
   }
```

I know I should create probably some function that will return the correct number of items per each width and then use this number as variable in the script. I just don't know how to write this js code correctly (not too good in js) so it works on resize too, without repeating the code too many times. Any js guru can help? :-)

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code inside this event handler (jQuery required)

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  var windowsize = $('#header .nav > .container').width();
  if (windowsize < 720) {
    var passItems = 1;
  } else if (windowsize > 720) {
    var passItems = 3;
  }
};
```

See example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lux2hoe0/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not try Responsive Slide, such Owl Responsive Slide. Link below:

[Owl Responsive Slide](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/responsive.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js I use it to great satisfaction, an example using the width just as a hint

```
   enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 45em)", {

        deferSetup : true,
        setup : function() {
            // load content via AJAX
        },
        match : function() {
            // show sidebar
        },
        unmatch : function() {
            // hide sidebar
        }  

    });
```